# C# Convert.ToDouble() loses decimal points when converting string to double

Tags: c#, double

Let's say we have the following simple code

```
        string number = "93389.429999999993";
        double numberAsDouble = Convert.ToDouble(number);
        Console.WriteLine(numberAsDouble);
```

after that conversion `numberAsDouble` variable has the value 93389.43. What can i do to make this variable keep the full number as is without rounding it? I have found that `Convert.ToDecimal` does not behave the same way but i need to have the value as double.

-------------------small update---------------------

putting a breakpoint in line 2 of the above code shows that the numberAsDouble variable has the rounded value 93389.43 before displayed in the console.

Comment: IIRC, it *is* parsing `number` correctly, however, it is being displayed as a rounded value when printed. Insert a breakpoint and confirm this. I may be wrong, though, hence the comment.

Comment: Please see if previous answers help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+double?sort=faq&pagesize=50 ...

Comment: Why do you _need_ it as a double?

Comment: @DStanley i need to pass the value as double to a library to make other calculations

Comment: And is passing in a value that is 0.000000000007 different going to make a material difference in those calculations?  If not just use a double.

Comment: @GiorgosManoltzas - That library isn't going to be able to be any more precise with a  `double` than your code will be.

Comment: That's what i though. But it is the library that exports this number. It is called Gurobi if you know it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`93389.429999999993` cannot be represented *exactly* as a 64-bit floating point number.  A `double` can only hold 15 or 16 digits, while you have 17 digits.  If you need that level of precision use a `decimal` instead.

(I know you say you *need* it as a double, but if you could explain why, there may be alternate solutions)

Comment: thanks for helping - i need to pass the exact value a double to a library to make calculations based on the value

Comment: @Chux - You win; Congrats!

Answer (score 6):

This is expected behavior.

A double can't represent every number exactly. This has nothing to do with the string conversion.

You can check it yourself:

```
Console.WriteLine(93389.429999999993);
```

This will print `93389.43`.

The following also shows this:

```
Console.WriteLine(93389.429999999993 == 93389.43);
```

This prints `True`.

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that there are two conversions going on here.  First you're converting the string to a double, and then you're converting that double back into a string to display it.

You also need to consider that a `double` doesn't have infinite precision; depending on the string, some data may be lost due to the fact that a double doesn't have the capacity to store it.

When converting to a double it's not going to "round" any more than it has to.  It will create the double that is closest to the number provided, given the capabilities of a double.  When converting that double to a string it's much more likely that some information isn't kept.

Answer (score 3):

See the following (in particular the first part of Michael Borgwardt's answer):

[decimal vs double! - Which one should I use and when?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)

A double will not always keep the precision depending on the number you are trying to convert

If you need to be precise you will need to use `decimal`

Answer (score 0):

This is a limit on the precision that a `double` can store.  You can see this yourself by trying to convert `3389.429999999993` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `double` type has a finite precision of 64 bits, so a rounding error occurs when the real number is stored in the numberAsDouble variable.

A solution that would work for your example is to use the `decimal` type instead, which has 128 bit precision. However, the same problem arises with a smaller difference.

For arbitrary large numbers, the `System.Numerics.BigInteger` object from the .NET Framework 4.0 supports arbitrary precision for integers. However you will need a 3rd party library to use arbitrary large real numbers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by number, but in more details (using google) the decimal precision sign=1 bit, mantissa=96 bit, exponent=29 bit? I haven't read anything clear on the exponent, and the total # of bits used is 128 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could truncate the decimal places to the amount of digits you need, not exceeding double precision.

For instance, this will truncate to 5 decimal places, getting 93389.42999. Just replace 100000 for the needed value

```
string number = "93389.429999999993";
decimal numberAsDecimal = Convert.ToDecimal(number);
var numberAsDouble = ((double)((long)(numberAsDecimal * 100000.0m))) / 100000.0;
```